# How Can I send an Email from Angular 6 with ASP.NET CORE web api?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

user will provide his email and password in the respective box and also give the recipient email address with a CC. Then it will be received in via a web api. In the mail there will be text such as "Total Sales Today" and a PDF will be attached. 
How can i do that? I am quite new in this regard.

[Click Here to See the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO5Ga.png)

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank You very much, just having a little problem.

'535: 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 127sm36312645pfy.56 - gsmtp'

My Username and password are correct.

Comment: Then mark my answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you can submit your data to API so you can use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).

This package provide support for IMAP & POP3

Example using POP3

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new Pop3Client ()) {
            // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s,c,h,e) => true;

            client.Connect ("pop.friends.com", 110, false);

            client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

            for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++) {
                var message = client.GetMessage (i);
                Console.WriteLine ("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
            }

            client.Disconnect (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about attachment? i need to attach a pdf with some text.

Comment: You can use formdata to submit it. MailKit already include a demo to attach attachment